How to work with shadow root with selenium in Python?
I would like to upload file at quick-actions.express.adobe.com, so I do the following:
driver.get("https://quick-actions.express.adobe.com/remove-background")
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "qa-standalone-app")
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
file_input = shadow_root.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")

But it says selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator.
I tried to access the element directly, but it doesn't work:
file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]'))
)
file_input.send_keys(file_path)

Is there any other way to upload the file there?
Upd.

It fails when multiple roots are used:
shadow_root1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-standalone-app").shadow_root
shadow_root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "standalone-quick-action").shadow_root
shadow_root3 = shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-app-root").shadow_root
shadow_root4 = shadow_root3.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "qa-app").shadow_root # fails here
shadow_root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-remove-background-editor").shadow_root
shadow_root6 = shadow_root5.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-workspace").shadow_root
shadow_root7 = shadow_root6.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-file-upload").shadow_root


The problem is that there are multiple levels of nested shadow-doms on the page that contain your desired INPUT.
Here's a couple levels of the pattern that you can follow,
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://quick-actions.express.adobe.com/remove-background")

shadow_root1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "qa-standalone-app").shadow_root
shadow_root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "standalone-quick-action").shadow_root

Just keep adding levels of shadow-root until you get to the level that has the desired INPUT and go from there...

Thank you, it helped! Why do we use CSS_SELECTOR instead of TAG_NAME here?

You can use either. Behind the scenes, By.TAG_NAME just gets changed to a CSS selector so I just use a CSS selector from the start. Either should work.

If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.
